# Enter full screen mode when tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement the function such that there's a image on the screen, when the image is tapped it then displays in full screen mode, and when tapped again in full screen mode, it back to the original size, like the following demo, how to achieve that?thanks

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

Comment: This is the library you are looking for: [GGFullscreenImageViewController](https://github.com/bogardon/GGFullscreenImageViewController). You can watch a video of it in action [on YouTube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdKS985eY1Q&feature=youtu.be) Try downloading that and setting up. It should look almost identically to the demo you provided.

Comment: @DominikHadl hey buddy, why do you change to put the solution here?I cant mark it as the correct solution if you put it here.

Comment: I didn't, a moderator did for some reason. I thought it was enough for an answer. Well, you can at least upvote the comment :)